# Customise hover plugin

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, hover, swt

I am currently writing a plug-in for eclipse in which i'm creating my own hover content, but i need to customize the hover itself so it will be interactive (will have buttons, collapsing lists, etc...).
is such a thing even possible?

i read somewhere that i might be able to create the interactive hover window itself using SWT to make a browser like window that shows HTML and that i might be able to attach it to my plugin and use it instead of the default and boring hover the eclipse supplies. But the problem is that i'm pretty sure i didn't understand it correctly.

so my question is, is such thing even possible? and if it is, how do i implement the solution?

Comment: Hover window for what? Is this a text editor you are writing? An existing editor you are try to change? Or just SWT controls?

Comment: I am trying to create my own hover for the defult eclipse editor. I want it to display inforamtion base on the static sturcture of the source code, But I need a button there or at least make the hover window support rich html

Comment: There are dozens of editors in Eclipse. If you mean the existing Java editor then that is difficult because it already has its own elaborate hover system.

Comment: So how can I override/costumise this system?.

Comment: For the Java editor you can add additional hovers using the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.javaEditorTextHovers` extension point. I don't think you can do much to change existing hovers.

Comment: I know that, cause thats how I create my own hover. But, what I want to know if I can customise the look of it and mybe add some buttons and etc.

Comment: Well I don't know that you know that because you asked such a vague question. Your extension can implement `ITextHoverExtension` to provide your own `IInformationControlCreator`

Comment: this is what I want to show in my plugin http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36099740/how-to-extend-my-own-hover-plugin